# Close current activity out previous activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-alertdialog

I have 2 activitys: 'A' and 'B'. 'A' read socket commands to open or close activity B. I havent problems with open B but with close I have.
My open command is simple:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, B.class);
startActivity(i);
```

So I wont to close it from 'A' but dont know how. Help me please!

P.s: Of course I can use from B

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, A.class);
startActivity(i);
```

but I have AlertDialog in activity A and It create only new problems (if use new intent).

![enter image description here][1]

Comment: Seriously, what are you talking about? What is 'out A', 'out B'? Why do you want to close an activity that is not even open?

Answer (score 0):

Do this :

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, B.class);
startActivity(i);
finish();
```

Comment: Sorry... I don't understand what you mean by OutA

Comment: public class A extends Activity
{private void openB {Intent i = new Intent(this, B.class);
startActivity(i);} private void closeB {//closeB}}

Comment: Oh.. so you want to remove the Activity from the Activity stack while you are in another activity. Is that it ? Why do you need to do this ? Maybe there is a better approach...

Comment: I write a socket-client and activity A is main room activity. It listens socket commands and if user is current winner in my game, room activity open game activity. But if user is not winner (it set server) so room activity must close game activity.

Comment: But i cant use finish(); or this.onBackPressed(); in game activity because it's static method. So I dont know solution.

Comment: OK. I'm lost... you need to post more code or images or something. Have you considered using a Service for the socket-client ??